# Monodevelop app not working on windows

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I am trying to make a Windows app in Mac using MonoDevelop, but when I try to use it on Windows I get this error

```
Could not load file or assembly "Mono.posix"
```

[image: error]
Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried putting the file mono.posix.dll in the same folder, but that still didnt fix it.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: In the command line when I initialize GTK#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your application has a dependency on the [Mono.Posix](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N%3aMono.Posix) assembly.

This assembly is deprecated in favor of [Mono.Unix](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N%3aMono.Unix). Since the latter is not available for Windows systems, my best guess is that the former also wasn't.

You would have to remove the dependency on that assembly (possibly rewriting parts of your app) if you want it to run on Windows.